# Dynamics CRM 4.0 Access Audit?

Tags: audit, microsoft-dynamics-crm

In Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0, is there any way to audit what records were viewed by a particular individual at what time without any special plugins? If you need a plugin, can you install the plugin and then look at past data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this, but there are plugins that can be deployed, and it's the only way to grab all data view, even from external applications that are using the SDK.

When plugins are deployed, they are active on particular events. So if you are looking a past data, the plugin will be launched, because the plugin is not aware of the underlying data.